# ¿Como hacer select de un inner join con multiples rows?

Tags: oracle, sql, select, plsql, join

Tengo un Query con la que intento traerme varios valores con un solo inner join, pero la cuestión es que me trae los diferentes valores como filas, por lo tanto me repite datos, lo que deseo es hacer un select de cada valor que trae el inner join para mostrarlos en diferentes columnas y de esta manera, no repetir los demas campos. acá agrego un ejemplo.

```
SELECT t3.valor,t1.* FROM tabla1 t1

   INNER JOIN tabla2 t2 --tabla intermedia entre t1 y t3 
         ON t1.id=t2.id

   INNER JOIN tabla3 t3 
         ON t2.id=t3.id


T3.VALOR            T1.ID       T1.EXPEDIENTE     T1.NOMBRECOMPLETO
Valor1                 1        10184488          JONATHAN GONZALEZ LOPEZ
Valor2                 1        10184488          JONATHAN GONZALEZ LOPEZ
Valor3                 1        10184488          JONATHAN GONZALEZ LOPEZ
```

lo que quiero es que las filas de la columna llama "VALOR", sean columnas diferentes, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
T3.VALOR1   T3.VALOR2    T3.VALOR3   T1.ID    T1.EXPEDIENTE  T1.NOMBRECOMPLETO
Valor1      Valor2       Valor3      1        10184488       JONATHAN GONZALEZ LOPEZ
```

Comment: Perdon no puedo ver las imagenes si pudieras poner mejor el query que quieres hacer y asi poder intentar ayudarte

Comment: Ya edité el post original y muestra el codigo en vez de las imagenes.

Comment: encontré un ejemplo que podrías leer para resolver tu problema: https://pgexercises.com/questions/joins/tjsub.html Espero te sirva.

Comment: tienes que ver cual es la columna que tiene diferentes valores, ya que debe de existir una que tenga diferentes valores por eso te repite los 3 registros, una vez que ya tienes detectado el registro que cambia de valor tienes que ver que es lo que vas hacer con ese registro, si quieres el máximo el mínimo o el promedio, y agrupar las demás columnas, esa es la manera correcta de resolver el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando una versión de Oracle 11G o posterior, puedes hacer uso de la sentencia PIVOT. Te dejo a continuación un ejemplo de como funciona.

```
WITH CARACTERISTICA_PERSONA AS (
     SELECT 1 ID_PERSONA, 'Nombre' CARACTERISTICA, 'Pedro' VALOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 1, 'Apellido', 'Perez' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 1, 'Edad', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'Nombre', 'Camila' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'Apellido', 'Páez' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'Edad', '12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'Nombre', 'Esteban' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'Apellido', 'Abondano' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'Edad', '20' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM CARACTERISTICA_PERSONA CP
PIVOT (MAX(VALOR) AS VALOR FOR (CARACTERISTICA)  IN ('Nombre', 'Apellido', 'Edad'))
```

Centrate en la parte del último `SELECT`, el `WITH` es solo para simular una tabla. Aquí está el resultado del query anterior:

[image: Resultado de query PIVOT]

De cualquier forma, te dejo también un enlace a un ejemplo completo de la sentencia PIVOT. En este mismo enlace encontrarás una solución alternativa a PIVOT para versiones de Oracle anteriores a la 11G.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

Edito mi respuesta agregando solución para Oracle 10.

```
 WITH CARACTERISTICA_PERSONA AS (
         SELECT 1 ID_PERSONA, 'Nombre' CARACTERISTICA, 'Pedro' VALOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'Apellido', 'Perez' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'Edad', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Nombre', 'Camila' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Apellido', 'Páez' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Edad', '12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Nombre', 'Esteban' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Apellido', 'Abondano' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Edad', '20' FROM DUAL)
    SELECT CP.ID_PERSONA,
           MAX(DECODE(CP.CARACTERISTICA, 'Nombre', CP.VALOR)) AS NOMBRE,
           MAX(DECODE(CP.CARACTERISTICA, 'Apellido', CP.VALOR)) AS APELLIDO,
           MAX(DECODE(CP.CARACTERISTICA, 'Edad', CP.VALOR)) AS EDAD
    FROM CARACTERISTICA_PERSONA CP
    GROUP BY CP.ID_PERSONA
    ORDER BY CP.ID_PERSONA
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, fijate que la versión que uso es la 10g, de que manera puedo hacer?

Comment: @jonathangonzalez Acabo de editar la respuesta agregando una solución para Oracle 10, usando la función DECODE.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, una solucion aunque muy antiperformante es pivotear varias veces la misma tabla T3:

```
SELECT t3_1.valor,
       t3_2.valor,
       t3_3.valor,
       t1.*
  FROM tabla1 t1                    INNER JOIN
       tabla2 t2   ON t1.id=t2.id   INNER JOIN
       tabla3 t3_1 ON t2.id=t3_1.id INNER JOIN
       tabla3 t3_2 ON t2.id=t3_2.id INNER JOIN
       tabla3 t3_3 ON t2.id=t3_3.id INNER JOIN
 WHERE t3_1.valor <> t3_2.valor
   AND t3_3.valor <> t3_2.valor
   AND t3_3.valor <> t3_1.valor;
```

Pero esto valdria solo si tenemos 3 valores fijos para cada registro de T1.


Otra manera es usando una funcion de agregacion:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(t3.valor, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t3.id)
       t1.*
  FROM tabla1 t1                INNER JOIN
       tabla2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id INNER JOIN
       tabla3 t3 ON t2.id=t3.id
 GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Pero entonces tendrias un soloc ampo que seria la concatenacion de los demas.

Personalmente creo que la mejor manera de obtener el dataset que queres es usar la query que ya tenes escrita y luego convertir el resultado usando un corte de control.